# RDC From Windows XP to Windows 7 Successful, Local Login Fails - How to Fix or Kill the RDC Process?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, kill

I successfully connected over RDC from a Win XP machine to a Win 7 machine. I then closed the RDC window. After that, I tried to log on locally to the Win 7 machine. All I get is a black screen with a mouse pointer. That mouse pointer will not move. Key commands do nothing as well. I then thought I would again try to RDC to the machine, but logging in to that user failed.

I really need to save what I was working on.

One thought I had was to log back in via RDC, but with a different Admin user I had set up and try to find the RDC process and kill it if it is still there, and hopefully I can log back in.

I do not know what the name of that process may be. Any ideas? Will killing it help? After searching, this RDC issue seems to have been happening for a while.

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors attached to the machine you're RDC'ing *from*? My work PC takes on the config of my home machine after I RDC into it, so where I'm going with this is the possibility that the logon screen could be where it *thinks* the other monitor is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only option, but this was my solution: hard reset of the computer. I didn't lose to much data. I would prefer that I get a better answer to this question in the future, but by that time, XP usage may be down, so it will not be much of a problem.